# Testcase with multitouch on Android?

Tags: android, testing, multi-touch

The TouchUtils class in the android documentation has functions like `drag()`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html#drag(android.test.InstrumentationTestCase,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20int)

but they do not support multi touch gestures, like a two finger swipe.

Looking at the `MotionEvent.obtain()` methods, there does not seem to be any way of invoking a "virtual" multi touch event from a testcase.

Anyone has got it working?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is no other way than to use the private function `MotionEvent.obtainNano()` to mock the multi touch events. Hopefully this will change in future versions.